# How to sort a filter function of strings

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract certain rows from this dataframe with the `filter` function:

[image]

Now I want to sort the extracted rows but the condition should be column `G`. Standard `sort` takes column `F` as condition.

[image]

But I want it to be sorted at column `G`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
=sort(filter(B3:C, regexmatch(C3:C, "Apple|Cat|Florida")), 2, 1)
```